# Is there any difference in null checking quality between `?.apply`, `?.run` and `?.let` in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I know the convention is to use `?.let` for null checking mutable variables because `?.let` will make sure that the variable we're checking doesn't change to null in the middle of the `block` that's being executed. Will the same hold true for `?.apply` and `?.run`?

One last thing, if the variable is immutable is it recommended to just use a simple `if`?

Comment: They are not actually the same thing, othewise there would be only one operator

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/from-java-programming-language-to-kotlin-the-idiomatic-way-ac552dcc1741

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any difference in null checking quality between `?.apply`, `?.run` and `?.let` in Kotlin?

Yes, they're all essentially the same when it comes to null checking quality. In fact, if you open the code for the `apply`, `let`, `with`, `also` & `run`. They're 'nearly' identical, they mainly differ on how the block get's executed, what argument is passed to the block and what value is returned.

```
inline fun <T, R> with(receiver: T, block: T.() -> R): R {
    return receiver.block()
}
inline fun <T> T.also(block: (T) -> Unit): T {
    block(this)
    return this
}
inline fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T {
    block()
    return this
}
inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R {
    return block(this)
}
inline fun <T, R> T.run(block: T.() -> R): R {
    return block()
}
```

They're really just syntactic sugar, that said it'd be a good idea for you to follow some basic rules/conventions on when to use what. Take a look at [article I](https://medium.com/@elye.project/mastering-kotlin-standard-functions-run-with-let-also-and-apply-9cd334b0ef84) & [article II](https://medium.com/@fatihcoskun/kotlin-scoping-functions-apply-vs-with-let-also-run-816e4efb75f5), they explain the difference between them in much greater detail than I can elaborate in this answer, along with basic conventions on when to use what.

> if the variable is immutable is it recommended to just use a simple `if`?

Yes, in fact, if you make an `if` check on a `val` variable, then the compiler will automatically understand that the variable will never be null inside the `if` block.

```
val user: User? = null;
if (user != null) {
  // user not null
  val name = user.name // won't show any errors
}
```

```
var user: User? = null;
if (user != null) {
  // user might be null
  // Since the value can be changed at any point inside the if block (or from another thread).
  val name = user.name // will show an error
}
```

Comment: Not entirely true. After the variable has been assigned a not-null value (i.e from a constructor), the compiler is smart enough to know that it will not be null for remainder of this code branch (or until it is assigned a nullable value again). 
The thread argument is also mostly applicable for fields of a class, not variables inside a function (there are edge cases though).

Comment: Actually, that behavior depends on whether you create the variable using `var` or `val`.

Comment: I was talking about `var` (since you cannot reassign `val`).
Example:


    fun bar(){
        var foo: String? = null
        if (foo == null) {
            foo = "bar"
            println(foo.toLowerCase()) // not an error, foo is never null, other thready will also never have access to this local variable
            foo = "".takeIf { false }
            println(foo.toUpperCase()) // error, foo may be null
            
        }
    }

Sorry about the formatting that does not work in comments :/

Comment: @PascalLudwig Uhm, your code proves my point. The `if` block provides no surety when it comes to `var` variables. It can only provide surety for `val` variables. Also, it's entirely possible for the variable `foo` to have it's value changed by an external thread whilst running in the `if` block.

Comment: No, it's not possible for a different thread to access a `var` declared inside a function

Comment: @gpunto It's possible to access if the `Thread` was created inside the function.

Comment: If you create a thread inside a function then the compiler is able to see inside the closure and can smart cast appropriately if the thread you are creating is not accessing the `var`. The point is that it is false to say that the smart cast is valid *only* for `val`s

Comment: No, the point is that it's inherently unsafe, the mere fact that there's some way(crooked/unplausible as it maybe) to change the variable's value **after** it has been checked by `if` and has entered the block makes it a very bad/unsafe choice.

Comment: The compiler will protect you when it is unsafe. It is not *always* unsafe. Smart casts can happen even with `var`s.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197064/discussion-between-chrisvin-jem-and-gpunto).